# Spring Data R2DBC parameters conditional binding for SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-webflux, reactor-netty, spring-data-r2dbc

I am facing a difficulty to bind a conditional parameters to SQL query using Spring Data R2DBC DatabaseClient. Two parameters can be null. Since the DatabaseClient requires to specify explicitly that the parameter is null, I have tried the following syntax but the conditional parameters were not appended to existing ones:

```
public Mono<Void> createAddress(Address address) {
    DatabaseClient.GenericExecuteSpec bindings = databaseClient.execute(addressesQueries.getProperty("addresses.insert"))
            .bind("line1", address.getLine1())
            .bind("zipCode", address.getZipCode())
            .bind("city", address.getCity())
            .bind("countryId", address.getCountry())
            .bind("id", address.getId()); // UUID

            if(address.getLine2() == null) {
                bindings.bindNull("line2", String.class);
            } else {
                bindings.bind("line2", address.getLine2());
            }
            if(address.getState() == null) {
                bindings.bindNull("state", String.class);
            } else {
                bindings.bind("state", address.getState());
            }

    return bindings.fetch().rowsUpdated().then();
}
```

SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO addresses(id,line1,line2,zip_code,city,state,country) VALUES(:id,:line1,:line2,:zipCode,:city,:state,:countryId)
```

I know that I can split the SQL query to handle cases with/without null parameters but it will be a little bit complicated if I have more that one conditional parameter.

Do you know a solution that can help me to keep one SQL query and handle conditional parameters in Java code?

Comment: Did you check if objects (`address.getLine2()`, `address.getState()`) are equal to `null`? Maybe they are empty instead?

Comment: Even if  the `line2` and `state` values are not null and not empty, I got this error: `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No parameter specified for [line2] in query`

Comment: I can be wrong but try re-assigning *bindings* object inside `if`/`else` conditions: `bindings = bindings.bindNull(...);`

Comment: Works as expected with re-assigning bindings object. Thank you @Parfait.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As commented, the *bindings* object is not changing with conditionals since you call `bind` and `bindNull` methods without saving such changed states back to object. Therefore  *line2* and *state* parameters are never populated with values. To fix, consider re-assigning *bindings* to update the object before its return:

```
if(address.getLine2() == null) { 
   bindings = bindings.bindNull("line2", String.class); 
} else { 
   bindings = bindings.bind("line2", address.getLine2()); 
} 

if(address.getState() == null) { 
   bindings = bindings.bindNull("state", String.class); 
} else { 
   bindings = bindings.bind("state", address.getState()); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use latest library io.r2bc.spi Parameters class and use in method similar to

`client .bind("lastName", Parameters.in(R2dbcType.VARCHAR, userDetailsModel.getLastName()))`